# Execute a JS file on the server through Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, jspdf

I have a js file that creates a pdf (with jsPDF), till now it was being executed on the client. Now I need the pdf file to be created and saved on the server, so instead of using a PHP library to create the PDF can I use the existing JS script and execute it on the server? With some research that I've done I found out that one way this might be done is through AJAX but I can't wrap my head around to do it.

Can you give me some guidelines on how to execute the JS script and how to pass my data from Wordpress to the JS file.

Comment: Do you have any server-side code that can even handle this? Because it's not as simple as "using a script" - you probably need a server that can handle these requests. I'm not sure if Wordpress has that capability. Also, AJAX is just a method to communicate with a server it would not, by itself, make the server do anything it can't.

Comment: You could send an Ajax call to a pdf function on the server-side. You will have to pass the needed parameters in the Ajax call.